# What does (l+v) :: ...(list + integer :: (cons operand) ..) mean in SML?

Tags: list, sml, smlnj

```
- fun addto (l,v) =
= if null l then nil
= else hd l + v :: addto (tl l,v);
val addto = fn : int list * int -> int list

addto ([1,2,3],2);
val it = [3,4,5] : int list
- addto ([1,2,3],~2);
val it = [~1,0,1] : int list
```

This is an SML function in my slides. I don't get how (l+v) can work here.
But it works actually:

```
addto ([1,2,3],2);
val it = [3,4,5] : int list
```

I am thinking it goes something like that:

```
   addto([1,2,3],2);  
   addto([2,3], 2);  
   addto([3], 2);   
   addto([],2)
```

now it's actually l nill so it returns it to addto([3], 2);
But what does `hd l + v :: addto (tl l,v);` mean anyway;
I thought that  the "cons" operator `::` has to be defined something like :
***<list_object_of_a_certain_type> ::*** 
And here my pseudo-name <list_object_of_a_certain_type> is actually integers in the example with addto([1,2,3],2).
But inside my function we have the phrase (l+v :: ..) while **l is a list and v is an int** so what is `l+v`?

p.s I am a complete beginner so forgive me if it all too simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First `::` is defined as:

```
datatype 'a list = nil | :: of 'a * 'a list
```

So, for instance, `1 :: [2, 3]` is the list `[1, 2, 3]`.

Then in your code, your expression is interpreted as:

```
((hd l) + v)) :: (addto (tl l,v))
```

So basically, your function can be rewritten as follows:

```ml
fun addto (l,v) =
if null l then nil  (*  if l is empty the result is the empty list  *)
else let
  val head = hd l  (*  take the first element of list l  *)
  val sum = head + v  (*  then add it v  *)
  val result_tail = addto (tl l,v)  (*  and compute x + v for all x in the tail of my list  *)
in
   sum :: result_tail  (*  the result is the sum I just computed followed by what the recursive call gave me  *)
end
```

Finally, note that in most cases, you don't need functions such as `null` or `head` because we write functions with pattern matching construction.  This greatly enhances readability and it is often the case that it suppresses the need for such functions.  For instance, `addto` can be rewritten more simply as:

```ml
fun addto ([], _) = []
  | addto (x :: tl, v) = (x + v) :: addto (tl, v)
```

Simpler isn't it?

Comment: thank you so much ! so that's it (l+ v) stands for taking the head of and adding it to v (so both integers).. I have a long way to be able to write the last function you wrote .. this is my first sml contact ever ! thank you so much